# Angular8 retrieve continuous data from Scala Play endpoint using HttpClient GET method

Tags: angular, scala

I'm having problems receiving data (continuously) from a Scala Play environment into an Angular 8 front-end project. 
For simpler data samples (static jsons) it was no problem to access the data (both GET and POST methods w/wo parameters), but when I attempt to get current time from an endpoint implemented in Scala it just isn't working. 
The Scala bit of code it's working as it should as I tested with curl commands and is returning the results expected.

In Angular I have a service which makes the request to Scala and the main component where I subscribe to the service function.
app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/index';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  private getTime = '/api/liveClock';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public retrieveTime() {
    return this.http.get(this.getTime, {responseType: 'text'}).pipe(
      map(response => response)
    );
  }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private appService: AppService) {
    this.appService.retrieveTime().subscribe({
      next(t) { console.log('d:', t); },
      error(e) {console.log('error:', e); },
      complete() { console.log('Finished'); }
    });
  }

  onInit() {
  }
}
```

Do you have any suggestion on make this work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: *"it just isn't working"* ok, what inst working? What error are you getting? HTTP error? Console error?

Comment: It is not printing anything. No error, no data.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution for my problem - a different implementation of the service request function:

```
public retrieveTime(): Observable<any> {
    const req = new HttpRequest(
      'GET', `${this.getTime}`, {responseType: 'text', reportProgress: true}
    );
    return this.http.request(req).pipe(
      map(response => response)
    );
  }
```

If anybody has a different idea, please enlighten me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add `reportProgress: true, observe: "events"` to your httpClient get request:

```
public retrieveTime() {
    return this.http.get(this.getTime, {responseType: 'text', observe: "events", reportProgress: true}).pipe(
      map(response => response)
    );
  }
```

Or you can use `EventSource`

```
const eventSource = new EventSource(this.getTime);
eventSource.onmessage = res => observer.next(res);
eventSource.onerror = x => observer.error(x);
```